# How to change the date font-size in a Task List Timeline milestone label?

Tags: css, task-list, style.css, timeline

it seems like a very simple thing to do, but I cannot get it done.
I am working with a timeline generated by a Task List on Sharepoint 2013. 
If I add a task to the Timeline, I am able to change the style of both text and date of that specific task on the graphic, but only if it's not set as a "milestone".
In the picture below I show you how what I mean: 
[image]
as you can see, I cannot change the date font-size, font-family etc of the Tasks set in the "milestone" format (the one that are put outside the graphic). Instead, the Title is perfectly changeable. Does anyone know how can I solve this problem? Maybe with some CSS? I am not able to point to that `span.ms-tl-milestoneLabelDate` with some CSS to manually change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `font-size` and `font-family` settings have been defined in the HTML of the `.ms-tl-milestoneLabel` element and in the children elements, you need to do forced CSS-changes, which means you need to add `!Important` to the style changes.

That said, you need to do the following changes:

```
.ms-tl-milestoneLabel {
    width: 100% !Important;
}
.ms-tl-milestoneLabelDate {
    font-size: <your font-size> !Important;
    font-family: <your font-family> !Important;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I was missing to add !Important. Thank you so much! You solved my problem :)

Comment: @supertrip86 Also note the change to the `.ms-tl-milestoneLabel`, as that element being the parent element has a fixed width which likely limits the amount of content the `LabelDate`-element would be able to display. Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out! It surely has avoided me a few more headaches :)